# Response not shown on setting the maxlength in Textfield of Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Tried setting the max length attribute of TextField of Material-Ui , but didn't found any property that can be set. Also Tried working by using the following code but still it is not working. The code is:-

```
<TextField
            label="Amazon Login"
            name="login"
            type = "number"
            fullWidth
            inputProps={{
              maxLength: 10,
            }}
            onChange={this.handle_value}
            margin="normal"

          />
```

Thanks for the Help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`maxLength` only works for text inputs. If you want to use it for numbers, then transform user input on the fly. Using `onInput` event. Like this:

```
<TextField
    label="Amazon Login"
    name="login"
    type="text"
    fullWidth
    inputProps={{
        maxLength: 10,
    }}
    onInput={(e) => { e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') }}
    margin="normal"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, are you trying to make the actual input field a certain width? If so, add a className to the TextField and style it that way. Something like the following should work...

```
  textField: {
   marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
   marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
   width: '100%',
  },

  ...

          <form>
            <TextField
              fullWidth
              label="Label"
              placeholder="Begin Typing..."
              helperText="Type your notes here"
              className={classes.textField}
              margin="normal"
            />
          </form>
```

Hope this helps!